# how to get AGE from DOB using "localDate" instead of writing in the "current year" using - user input-?

Tags: java

How do I change this code to make it get Age from Local Date instead of using "what is the current year"?

this is what i have so far:

//----------------------------------------------------------------

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  try {
         System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
            String name = input.nextLine();

         System.out.println("Please enter your birth date: ");
            String date = input.nextLine();

         System.out.println("please enter your birth month:");
            String month = input.nextLine();

         System.out.println("please enter your birth year:");
            String year = input.nextLine();

         System.out.println("please enter current year:");
            String cYear = input.nextLine();


             int bDate = Integer.parseInt(date);
             int bMonth = Integer.parseInt(month);
             int bYear = Integer.parseInt(year);
             int ccYear = Integer.parseInt(cYear);

          int age = ccYear - bYear;
          int totalMonth = 12;
          int yourMonth = totalMonth - bMonth;

    System.out.println(" Hi " + name + " your are " + age + " years  ");
  } catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("");
  }
}
```

Comment: What part of this problem do you need help with?

Comment: What does "User Local Date" mean?

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to get the current year using the standard `Calendar` API.

```
int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

From there, you just need to plug that into the right place in your code.